# When to attribute things in this world to things not of this world

Tags: intervention, spirituality

Some Christians take every situation and claim "God did this" or "the holy spirit is moving in this place" when something good happens, and "Satan did this" or "this place has evil spirits"  when something bad happens. Sometimes you even hear "God did this out of anger/jealousy" when something bad happens (see [natural disasters](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-disasters)).

The Bible shows countless times where God intervenes (see the plagues in Exodus) and also where evil spirits intervene (see demon-possession in Matthew). Ultimately God is in control, but how can one determine if a situation occurred due to divine intervention?

Comment: I feel like an additional frame of reference is necessary here.  First, are you asking on what grounds people make these claims? If so, we need to know specifically who these people are.  Are you asking if their claims are true? If so, we need to know by which standard to judge them--in other words, a [doctrinal tradition](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/732/whats-the-difference-between-doctrine-and-doctrinal-tradition)